# Property pipe does not exist on type void Angular

Tags: angular

This is my code it gives me error here when i am using first with pipe in angular 10

```
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service';

submitForm(){ 
      this.submitted = true;
      if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
        return;
     }

      this.loading = true;
      console.log(this.f.username.value)
      this.executeImportantAction();
      this.authenticationService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
            .pipe(first())                                                           >>> Error here
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                },
                error => {
                    this.error = error;
                    this.loading = false;
                });
      }
```

This is my Login function in authenticateService which is down bellow

```
  login(userId: string, userPassword: string) {
        this.http.post<any>(this.Url,'/' + {userId} + '/' + {userPassword})
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                return user;
            }));
    }
```

That Error was gone but now i am getting the new error

```
 login(userId: string, userPassword: string): Observable<User> {
        this.http.post(this.Url,'/' + {userId} + '/' + {userPassword})
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                return user;
            }));
    }
```

Comment: have you import `pipe` from `rxjs`?

Comment: yes i have imported first and pipe

Comment: This question could be improved if you would show us the error you got but as @Derek.W pointed out, it is likely a problem with imports. Try adding the line `import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';` at the top of your file. **Edit:** You should not import pipe, maybe that could be where the error reside.

Comment: And what's the return object type of `login` in authenticationService? It's observable?

Comment: Also, are you sure that the observable is emitting a value? The `first` operator will throw an exception if no value is emitted. So really, without you providing the error, we are in the dark.

Comment: @DavidFontes and  i have updated my question

Comment: you have to `return this.http`, right now login is not returning anything (the return inside the map of the http pipe is a return for the pipe, login still returns void)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return this.http, right now login is not returning anything (the return inside the map of the http pipe is a return for the pipe, login still returns void)

you could have noticed this if you used TS to its full extent. Change your function types to:

`login(userId: string, userPassword: string): Observable<User>` (you should create an interface for the user, instead of using any)

`this.http.post<dont-use-any-here>`

With types, TS would have warned you with `this functions expects to return an observable, but you are returning void`

```
login(userId: string, userPassword: string): Observable<User> {
        return this.http.post(this.Url,'/' + {userId} + '/' + {userPassword})
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                return user;
            }));
    }
```

Comment: now i am getting the some error i have updated my question thread

Comment: are you returning the http post in your login method inside your service?

Comment: @Asad please check the update to my answer. Last paragraph. You have to return the http post

Comment: this is my new thread please help me at this thread

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278950/a-function-whose-declared-type-is-neither-void-nor-any-must-return-a-value-a