# A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value Angular

Tags: angular

I am getting this error when using observable class was working fine before

```
  login(userId: string, userPassword: string): Observable<User> {          >>> I am getting error here
        this.http.post(this.Url,'/' + {userId} + '/' + {userPassword})
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                return user;
            }));
    }
```

This is the Interface

```
 export interface User {
         success:string
         userId:string
         userPassword:string
         token?: string
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact error/log?

Comment: Add a `return` just before `this.http.post`

Comment: Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
    Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'User': success, userId, userPassword

Comment: @frunkad it is not working

Comment: Before returning the `user`, typecast it. `return (user as User)`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `return` before `this.http.post` and use `tap`

```
  login(userId: string, userPassword: string): Observable<User> {     
      return this.http.post(this.Url,'/' + {userId} + '/' + {userPassword})
            .pipe(tap(user => {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
            }));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two changes

- Typecasted User
- returned Observable

  ```
  login(userId: string, userPassword: string): Observable<User> {  
        return this.http.post(this.Url,'/' + {userId} + '/' + {userPassword})
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                return (user as User);
            }));
    }
  ```